# Build failing after publishing

Tags: vb.net, cruisecontrol.net, web-deployment-project

I am using Web Application Deployment for publishing on IIS.  At first I have converted my website to a web application. My application compiles and build fine on my VS2005. But when I try to run it via CC.net. It comes up with a 100's of errors. Following is the list of someof the errors that keep repating in the same file.

```
errorBC30284: function 'GetCannotChangeMessage' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a function in a base class.
errorBC30451: Name 'GetAndChangesCanBePerformed' is not declared.
errorBC30456: 'GetStatusMessage' is not a member of 'Object'.
```

Any one plz let me know why my build is failing with these errors. As functions are overridable in base class and also names declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to just upload it as a web site ( not application) to your hosting ?
I always just upload web site without any builds and it's run fine.